# Incompatible license aborted. Press any key to continue

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10, grubrescue, license

I recently using windows 10 for a while. But when I wanted to use Ubuntu I can't able to see dual os selection mode and after some seconds it displays **incompatible license aborted press any key to exit** when I press key it boot into windows how could I get into Ubuntu. Please help

Comment: Try the fallowing tutorial and tell me if it doesnt work:

https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: I have only older image of ubuntu, and when I try to install boot-repair it's not installed. Whether I shoul try again with newer image??

Comment: What computer do you own? (Company,Model)